# How to natural sort mysql databases in datagrip?

Tags: mysql

I am using JetBrains DataGrip to manage my MySQL databases. I have over 100 schemas with similar names. Something like db_1, db_2, db_3 etc. The problem is that they are listed like this in the "Database" panel:

```
db_0
db_1
db_10
db_100
db_11
db_12
```

... and you get the point. db_2 is not listed until after db_19. How can I reorder my databases manually or in a naturally sorted order. Datagrip actually does nat-sort them in the "Database tools">"Manage shown schemas" menu.

Thanks in advance. I have been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: Rename your databases and add leading zeros. i.e. `db_1` to `db_001`, `db_12` to `db_012`, etc. You may use underscore instead of leading zeros too - i.e. `db___1` and `db__12` respectively.

Comment: This would not work in my case because I have admin panels that list info from multiple databases. There is a main database table that lists these databases. I would have to rewrite all code that loops through this table (which contains the number) and concatenates the name.